# Exmo API. Не могу законнектится

Tags: python, api

Не работает API exmo.me
Что делаю не так?
Сталкивался кто?

```
import requests


url = "https://api.exmo.com/v1.1/trades"

payload='pair=BTC_USD'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response)
```

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.exmo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.1/trades (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017C7D006580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке не обновили данные о новом домене.
Решение `exmo.com` заменить `exmo.me`